# Opening link in a new tab doesn`t use the proper URL?

Tags: php, css

I have a web project with the directory structure

root (which has index.php)
-- reports
    -- a.php

Now, the usual homepage URL is 
http://abc.co m/index.php#reports/a.php

This works fine. Index.php has most of the CSS code which it uses as a base in the other php files.

The problem is when a user opens the page in a new tab the link changes to

http://abc.co m/reports/a.php

so no Index.php hence all CSS in lost.

Should I change the directory structure or is there any other work around?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `base_href` tag to change where the relative urls start from:

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/index.php/" target="_blank">
```

Or you could set up Apache to `mod_rewrite` so all requests go through `index.php`, which is most likely what you want to do.  To do that, the simplest way is to place the following in your `.htaccess` file in your websites root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```